# Environment Variables get Trimmed with "$" in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-dotenv

So I have an environment variable in my .env file.

```
TESTMSG=abc$efg
```

And in rails console when I try to retrieve this data, it gets trimmed and the part after &  doesn't get printed.

```
2.6.0 :001 > ENV['TESTWORD']
=> "abc"
```

How to get the complete word. I even tried puting quotes around the word like this.

```
TESTMSG="abc$efg"
```

which didn't work.

Comment: Are you using the dotenv gem? According to the [docs](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#variable-substitution): _"If a value contains a `$` and it is not intended to be a variable, wrap it in single quotes."_

Comment: This likely follows bash rules, so yeah, what Stefan says. It's interpolating `$efg` as set here.

Comment: It is possible to escape with `\\` before special symbol

Answer (score 2):

Use the quotation marks when the string contains spaces or certain special character and certain syntaxes.
because dollar sign (that is used to expand a variable – see below),
.env files are, according to the page linked by you, regular bash scripts.

```bash
my_var=42
VARIABLES="foo ${my_var}"  # Gives “foo 42”.
```

Escape dollar sign in string by shell script (and .env also)

- use \ before $

```
TESTMSG="abc\$efg" # or abc\$efg

3.0.2 :001 > ENV['TESTMSG']
 => "abc$efg"
```

- or just type it with single quotes

```rb
TESTMSG='abc$efg' 
3.0.2 :001 > ENV['TESTMSG']
 => "abc$efg"
```

Comment: I think to make more understandable you can add something like `efg=12345` and `TESTMSG=abc$efg` to show that is interpolation

Comment: Also `TESTMSG=abc\$efg` (without quotes) should work